# SSIS TPT Import error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, teradata, ssis-2008, attunity

When i try to load data from excel source to the teradata with ssis and using microsoft connector for teradata by attunity 1.2 i got below error, what am i missing?

[Teradata Destination [23]] Error: TPT Import error encountered during Initiate phase. Could Not Find Message Catalog opermsgs
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: component "Teradata Destination" (23) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80004005.

My configuration is:

- SSIS 2008 R2
- Teradata 15
- Attunity 1.2

Comment: Are you running in 32 bit mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

today I faced with the same error.

My problem was solved, when I added a way to TPT folders in PATH runtime variable.

This folders are:

```
C:\Program Files\Teradata\client\14.10\Teradata Parallel Transporter\bin64;
C:\Program Files\Teradata\client\14.10\Teradata Parallel Transporter\msg64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Teradata\client\14.10\Teradata Parallel Transporter\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Teradata\client\14.10\Teradata Parallel Transporter\msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error.
Using Visual Studio 2012 with Data Tools installed.
SQL Server 2014 Source.  TD destination.
Attunity 2.0 Teradata.

You have to have Java client installed Correctly for TPT.
I had the path as shown in the above (all 4) but still was getting error.  I rebooted and error was resolved.  This TD upload in INSANE fast..  I'm at 500 million in just a few minutes.. works great.